# MvvmCross ViewModel is always null in Xamarin.Android but It is accessible in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, viewmodel

Please find the complete description of the question [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/139095/mvvmcross-viewmodel-is-always-null-in-xamarin-android-but-it-is-accessible-in-xamarin-ios#latest).

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the code you use to navigate between the ViewModels and the class attributes you are setting in Android (https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/android/android-view-presenter?scroll=655)? Because I don't see in your code any of that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a link only question, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing to supply Attributes in your fragment.

For Example:

```
[MvxFragmentPresentation(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.frameLayout, AddToBackStack = true)]
    [Register("myProj.mobile.views.SorryView")]
    class SorryView : MvxFragment<SorryViewModel>
```

Here, MainViewModel is associated with MainActivity, SorryView is a fragment gets presented on MainActivity.

Comment: Everything was there except Setup Class. I re-added all the packages in solution, added setup class in android and it worked. Thank you :)